# Working with dates contingent on other factors in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm having trouble working out the best way to answer this problem. I'm worried that this may be due to a fundamental misunderstanding about analyses (more on that later). The problem is this: of about 25,000 transactions, I need to find which customers called within two months of lapsing in their subscription.

```
id = unique customer ID

call = 1 signifies the observation is a call

lapse = 1 signifies the observation is a lapse
```

Note that if any customer has both a call and a lapse on the same date there would be two entries for that customer on that date; the customer can have multiple calls on one date (each its own observation and its own row in the df); but any customer can only one lapse per date.

The mini-df without solution:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
             date = dmy(c("01-01-2014", "07-02-2014",   "05-03-2014",   "14-02-2014",   "15-04-2014",   "17-04-2014",   "11-05-2014",   "19-08-2014",   "07-10-2014",   "21-12-2014",   "04-06-2010",   "06-03-2012",   "12-07-2012",   "13-07-2012",   "14-01-2014",   "05-05-2014",   "19-08-2014",   "19-08-2014",   "13-02-2013",   "11-11-2013",   "04-03-2014",   "10-12-2014",   "02-03-2017",   "03-03-2017")), 
             call = c(1,    0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0),
             lapse = c(0,   1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1))
```

...and the solution vector:

```
df$call_2months_or_less_before_lapse <- c(1,    0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0)
```

So, I cringe when I say this, but I can solve this problem in Excel. However, I refuse to give up - I'm never going back!

So I would like to be pointed in the right direction concerning code for a solution, particularly if that direction is somewhere in the tidyverse. However, I'm worried that I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of tidy data. This is the first problem I couldn't brute-force my way through since I started learning R.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function using only base R code to find the time interval, in days, between each lapse date and the most recent call date immediately preceding it. Then you can use dplyr to group your data frame by customer ID and apply the function to each customer. The dplyr part could also be done with base R code using `split()` and `lapply()`.

```
# Function that finds time to most recent call before a lapse.
time_to_most_recent_call <- function(x) {
  # Extract vector of dates when the subscription lapsed, and vector of dates when customer called.
  lapse_dates <- x$date[x$lapse == 1]
  call_dates <- x$date[x$call == 1]
  # Get all pairwise time intervals in days between lapse and call.
  time_intervals <- sapply(lapse_dates, function(z) z - call_dates)
  # Find most recent call before each lapse (only look at positive time intervals)
  shortest_intervals <- apply(time_intervals, 2, function(z) min(z[z >= 0]))  
  # Return result (also include flag if it's between 0 and 60)
  return(data.frame(lapse_date = lapse_dates, 
                    interval = shortest_intervals, 
                    within2months = shortest_intervals >= 0 & shortest_intervals <= 60))
}

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(time_to_most_recent_call(.))
```

This returns, for each customer and each lapse date, the interval time in days from the most recent call to that lapse. It also flags it if the interval was less than 60 days (2 months). It returns warning messages if the customer never called before the lapse because in that case the minimum interval is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to mark all calls for each customer within a period of two months before a lapse.

This can be solved by *aggregating in a non-equi join* using `data.table`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, answer := 
            df[.(id = id, date1 = date, date2 = date %m+% months(2)), 
               on = .(id, date >= date1, date <= date2),
               as.integer(any(lapse == 1)), by = .EACHI]$V1][
                 call == 0, answer := 0][]
```

> ```
>     id       date call lapse call_2months_or_less_before_lapse answer
>  1:  1 2014-01-01    1     0                                 1      1
>  2:  1 2014-02-07    0     1                                 0      0
>  3:  1 2014-03-05    0     1                                 0      0
>  4:  1 2014-03-14    1     0                                 0      1
>  5:  1 2014-04-15    1     0                                 1      1
>  6:  1 2014-04-17    1     0                                 1      1
>  7:  1 2014-05-11    0     1                                 0      0
>  8:  1 2014-08-19    1     0                                 0      0
>  9:  1 2014-10-07    1     0                                 0      0
> 10:  1 2014-12-21    0     1                                 0      0
> 11:  3 2010-06-04    0     1                                 0      0
> 12:  3 2012-03-06    0     1                                 0      0
> 13:  3 2012-07-12    0     1                                 0      0
> 14:  3 2012-07-13    0     1                                 0      0
> 15:  3 2014-01-14    1     0                                 0      0
> 16:  3 2014-05-05    0     1                                 0      0
> 17:  3 2014-08-19    1     0                                 1      1
> 18:  3 2014-08-19    0     1                                 0      0
> 19:  4 2013-02-13    0     1                                 0      0
> 20:  4 2013-11-11    1     0                                 0      0
> 21:  4 2014-03-04    1     0                                 0      0
> 22:  4 2014-12-10    1     0                                 0      0
> 23:  4 2017-03-02    1     0                                 1      1
> 24:  4 2017-03-03    0     1                                 0      0
>     id       date call lapse call_2months_or_less_before_lapse answer
> ```

Note that row 4 exhibits a flaw in OP's sample dataset which will be discussed in the *Data* section below.

#### Explanation

The idea is to look for each row (for simplicity, we take calls *and* lapses likewise) if there is any lapse for this customer within the actual date and the actual date plus 2 months. So, we look ahead - not behind. If so, the answer is `1` for this row or `0` if not.

The key part is the *aggregation in a non-equi join*:

```
df[.(id = id, date1 = date, date2 = date %m+% months(2)), 
   on = .(id, date >= date1, date <= date2), 
   as.integer(any(lapse == 1)), by = .EACHI]
```

`df` is right joined with a `data.table` which is created on-the-fly using `.()` consisting of `id`, `date`, and `date %m+% months(2)`. Here, we use `lubridate`'s month arithmetic to meet OP's requirement of a *2 months* period (not 60 days).

By the join conditions in the `on` parameter, all rows are picked which fulfill the conditions, i.e., have the same `id` and the date is within the date range. These matching rows are immediately aggregated by the join conditions (`by = .EACHI`) using `any()` as aggregation function.

Now, this result is appended to `df` as a new column `answer`. The `:=` operator updates `df` *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

Finally, the `answer` is corrected for the rows which contain *no* calls.

In the beginning, `setDT(df)` is used to coerce `df` to class `data.table`.

#### Data

The following dataset is used in this answer:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(
  id    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  date  = dmy(c("01-01-2014", "07-02-2014", "05-03-2014", "14-03-2014", "15-04-2014", "17-04-2014", 
                "11-05-2014", "19-08-2014", "07-10-2014", "21-12-2014", "04-06-2010", "06-03-2012", 
                "12-07-2012", "13-07-2012", "14-01-2014", "05-05-2014", "19-08-2014", "19-08-2014",
                "13-02-2013", "11-11-2013", "04-03-2014", "10-12-2014", "02-03-2017", "03-03-2017")), 
  call  = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  lapse = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

Note that row 4 is different to OP's original dataset. For row 4, the OP has given the date `"14-02-2014"` which is not in increasing order of dates. I am assuming this is a typo and should read `"14-03-2014"` to be in line with the increasing order of all other dates.

Unfortunately, this presumed typo had also an effect on the expected result in column `call_2months_or_less_before_lapse` which the OP has given as `0`. However, it should be `1` in any case. For `"14-02-2014"`, there is a lapse within two months in row 3. For `"14-03-2014"`, there is a lapse within two months in row 7.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's possible to solve your and similar problems problem in R. Morever, you may do it (qite) easily with the very basics of R.

First of all, let formulate the problem more precisely. Unfortunately, not all details are clear from your post. I'll try to guess and assume as an initial point the following problem formulation:

For **each customer** and **each lapse** we need to find all the calls took place **2 or less month earlier** than the date of the lapse and mark all the found events (let say, as `1` in the column of flags). Besides, we can guess from your example that if many events correspond to the single date, **only the call-events** should be flagged.

I would propose to solve you problem in following steps:

**1. Write the function to find all dates in the 2 months periods before
    the each lapse of the whole df.**

```
# @df_to_proceed is the data frame to be looked up
# @current_df_i is the row index of the precessed lapse
    Find2MonthsEarlier <- function(df_to_proceed, current_df_i) {
    # the customer ID for the given lapse
    given_id <- df_to_proceed$id[current_df_i] 
    # select the entries of the df corresponding 
    # to the 2-month period before the given lapse
    current_date <- df_to_proceed$date[current_df_i]
    # assume 2 month as simply 60 days
    date_2month_earlier <- as_date(current_date - 60)
    period_2month_earlier <- interval(date_2month_earlier, current_date)
    # select a subset for the certain customer and the 2-month period 
    # before the given lapse
    subset_2month_earlier <- df_to_proceed[with(df_to_proceed, 
        (date %within% period_2month_earlier & id == given_id)), ]
    subset_2month_earlier_reordrd <- subset_2month_earlier[order(subset_2month_earlier$date), ]
    # finds the row with the latest call within 2-month period before the given lapse
    i_of_latest_call_within2months <- nrow(subset_2month_earlier_reordrd) - 
        match(table = rev(subset_2month_earlier_reordrd$call), x = 1) +
        1
    date_of_latest_call_within2months <- subset_2month_earlier_reordrd[i_of_latest_call_within2months,
        "date"]
    # extract all the dates between the latest call within 2-month period 
    # before the given lapse (for the certain customer!)
    dates_to_flag <- subset_2month_earlier$date[subset_2month_earlier$date <=
        date_of_latest_call_within2months]  
    return(list(Subset = subset_2month_earlier, 
        LatestDate = as_date(date_of_latest_call_within2months),
        ID = given_id, FlaggedDates = dates_to_flag))
}
```

**2. Find row indices of all lapses in the df**

```
i_of_lapse <- which(df$lapse == 1)
```

**3. Apply the function along all the lapses** with special processing of the cases of multiply events for the same date

```
for (i in i_of_lapse) {
    test_list <- Find2MonthsEarlier(df_to_proceed = df, 
        current_df_i = i)
    # duplicated dates are processed differently
    dates_with_dupl <- unique(test_list[["FlaggedDates"]][duplicated(test_list[["FlaggedDates"]])])
    # check length(dates_with_dupl) to prevent loss of the data
    if (length(dates_with_dupl) > 0) {
        dates_without_dupl <- test_list[["FlaggedDates"]][!(test_list$date %in% dates_with_dupl)]
    } else {
        dates_without_dupl <- test_list[["FlaggedDates"]]
        }
    # entries with duplicated dates are flagged only if corresponding call = 1
    df[(df$date %in% dates_with_dupl & 
            df$id == test_list[["ID"]] & df$call == 1),
        "flag_calls_2month_earlier_inR"] <- 1
    df[(df$date %in% dates_without_dupl & 
        df$id == test_list[["ID"]]),
        "flag_calls_2month_earlier_inR"] <- 1   
    }
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is the values of `df$call_2months_or_less_before_lapse[c(3, 4)]` corresponding to the dates `"07-02-2014"` and `"14-02-2014"`. It was a `call == 1` for `"14-02-2014"` and it was a `lapse == 1` for `"05-03-2014"`. It seems, it should be still a `flag == 1` for both `"07-02-2014"` and `"14-02-2014"`, but actually they are `0`. So, there is something wrong either with the problem formulation or with the example values. It would be great if your could please check and comment that issue.